# Android studio Illegal char <:> at index

Tags: android-studio

When I am trying to switch build variant from release to debug in android studio, I am getting this error:

```
Illegal char <:> at index 52: C:/Projects/Android/ProjectName/.idea/modules/app/C:.Projects.Android.ProjectName.app.androidTest.iml
```

Yesterday it was working fine. Strange thing is that I cant find text which is causing error. I can't find file with that content.

Building in release mode is working fine.

What should I do?

Comment: have you tried deleting the .idea folder ? i think usually this is ignored in most git projects so i'm not sure why this could be giving you issues

Comment: You have twice `C:` in that path. That is impossible as `:` is a forbidden charakter if it is not a partition indicator. The error message tells you all...

Comment: Please change `android` tag to `android-studio`.

Comment: Comment from a_local_nobody helped! Thanks.